# How to fix image showing first and then fadeIn slowly kicks in later

Tags: javascript, jquery

The image shows up first before **fadeOut** and so it creates a flickering effect. I want the image to change after **fadeOut** is called and before **fadeIn** is called. Could someone help?

**[JSFiddel: https://jsfiddle.net/t20ozdvn/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/t20ozdvn/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="output" id="output">
  <h1 class="cursor"></h1>
</div>
<div class="images">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4Y054xz3/video-1.jpg">
</div>
```

JS:

```
// values to keep track of the number of letters typed, which quote to use. etc. Don't change these values.
var i = 0,
  a = 0,
  isBackspacing = false,
  isParagraph = false;

// Typerwrite text content. Use a pipe to indicate the start of the second line "|".  
var textArray = [
  "This is the line one text.",
  "Another line goes here that is awesome."
];

var images = {
  0: { 
  "urls": [
     "https://i.postimg.cc/4Y054xz3/video-1.jpg"
  ]},
  1: {
  "urls": [
     "https://i.postimg.cc/8jt43HcM/video-2.jpg"
  ]}
}

// Speed (in milliseconds) of typing.
var speedForward = 100, //Typing Speed
  speedWait = 1000, // Wait between typing and backspacing
  speedBetweenLines = 1000, //Wait between first and second lines
  speedBackspace = 25; //Backspace Speed

//Run the loop
typeWriter("output", textArray);

function changeImage(number) {
  var imagesArr = [];
  images[number].urls.forEach(function(url){
    imagesArr.push('<img src="'+ url +'">');
  });
  $('.images').html(imagesArr)
  .fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(".images").attr('src',imagesArr);
  })
  .fadeIn(400);
}

function typeWriter(id, ar, callback) {
  var element = $("#" + id),
    aString = ar[a],
    eHeader = element.children("h1"), //Header element
    eParagraph = element.children("p")
    count = 0; //Subheader element

  // Determine if animation should be typing or backspacing
  if (!isBackspacing) {

    // If full string hasn't yet been typed out, continue typing
    if (i < aString.length) {

      // If character about to be typed is a pipe, switch to second line and continue.
      if (aString.charAt(i) == "|") {
        isParagraph = true;
        eHeader.removeClass("cursor");
        eParagraph.addClass("cursor");
        i++;
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeWriter(id, ar);
        }, speedBetweenLines);



        // If character isn't a pipe, continue typing.
      } else {
        // Type header or subheader depending on whether pipe has been detected
        if (!isParagraph) {
          eHeader.text(eHeader.text() + aString.charAt(i));
        } else {
          eParagraph.text(eParagraph.text() + aString.charAt(i));
        }
        i++;
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeWriter(id, ar);
        }, speedForward);
      }

      count++;

      // If full string has been typed, switch to backspace mode.
    } else if (i == aString.length) {

      isBackspacing = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(id, ar);
      }, speedWait);
    }

    // If backspacing is enabled
  } else {

    // If either the header or the paragraph still has text, continue backspacing
    if (eHeader.text().length > 0 || eParagraph.text().length > 0) {

      // If paragraph still has text, continue erasing, otherwise switch to the header.
      if (eParagraph.text().length > 0) {
        eParagraph.text(eParagraph.text().substring(0, eParagraph.text().length - 1));
      } else if (eHeader.text().length > 0) {
        eParagraph.removeClass("cursor");
        eHeader.addClass("cursor");
        eHeader.text(eHeader.text().substring(0, eHeader.text().length - 1));
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(id, ar);
      }, speedBackspace);

      // If neither head or paragraph still has text, switch to next quote in array and start typing.
      } else {

        isBackspacing = false;
        i = 0;
        isParagraph = false;
        a = (a + 1) % ar.length; //Moves to next position in array, always looping back to 0
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeWriter(id, ar);
        }, 50);

        changeImage(a);
      }
    }  
  }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want, could you elaborate more... do you want the text to show first and then the image starts to fade in along...

Comment: I think he wants the old image to fade out, then the image gets changed right before it fades back in. Currently, the image changes first, then fades out, then fades back in, and it looks extremely weird.

Comment: If you see the images, you will notice that it flickers. I want to remove that flicker.

Comment: @Aplet123 Yes exactly that. It's actually fadeOut is working but the next image loads before the fadeIn is called and hence the weird effect.

Comment: $('.images').html(imagesArr)
  .fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(".images").attr('src',imagesArr)
  .fadeIn(400);;
  }).hide();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want, do not re-append your whole image html just control the url's src attributes and then manipulate with the fade effects.

Fiddle proof: https://jsfiddle.net/uLzprfa7/

Explanation: after image fades out, push the new url to the src attribute and finally fade in.

```
function changeImage(number) {
  var imagesArr = [];
  images[number].urls.forEach(function(url) {
    imagesArr.push(url);
  })
  $('#my-image').fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(".images").children().attr('src', imagesArr).fadeIn(400);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank You. if I increase the fadeOut timing from 400 to 1000, the next image loading gets delayed but I don't see the fadeOut effect.

Comment: @ElaineByene remove the hide() at the end, see my answer again

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.